# Why doesn't font family feature appear in TinyMCE ?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE control to edit and enter text. I want to put FONT-FAMILY feature i.e. menu toolbar into it but couldn't.

```
  tinyMCE.init({
            selector: '#<%=txtBoxBody.ClientID%>',
              mode: "textareas",
              toolbar: 'fontsizeselect',
              fontsize_formats: '8pt 9pt 10pt 11pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 20pt 22pt 24pt 26pt 28pt 36pt 48pt 72pt'

          });
```

how can i ? Like a separate FONT FAMILY menu for selecting fonts

Answer (score 0):

Works like a charm. See my fiddle here: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Vofaab

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    toolbar: 'fontsizeselect',
    fontsize_formats: '8pt 9pt 10pt 11pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 20pt 22pt 24pt 26pt 28pt 36pt 48pt 72pt'
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="dump.php">
    <textarea name="content"></textarea>
</form>
```

Maybe your selector is not working. When asking a Stackoverflow question you should exlicitly name what is not working. I.e. the editor does not render or the fonsioze select does not appear in the tinymce UI.

Answer (score 0):

### TinyMCE version 3

Use "theme_advanced_buttons<1-n>_add" instead of "toolbar".
The theme has to be set to "advanced" (It's the default setting).
e.g.:

```
theme_advanced_buttons1_add: "fontsizeselect"
```

References:

> - https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/Configuration3x/Configuration3x@theme_advanced_buttons_1_n_add/
> - https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/buttons
> - https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/Configuration3x/Configuration3x@theme_advanced_font_sizes/
> - https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/Configuration3x/Configuration3x@theme/